# "Favorites" link in StackExchange "user menu"

Tags: feature-request

I think "Favorites" should be one of the links in top user menu:

> Stack **Exchange** v ... ... ... username & reputation | **favorites** | log out | parent | about | faq

If user stared question as "Favorite", he did not done that beacose of other users (others to see that question in his profile). He favorited **interesting** question, so maybe "Favorite" list should be "one click closer", in top horizontal menu, for example.

Answer (score 3):

I think two clicks to get favourites is fine.  I'm not sure what else - if anything - I'd put on the top bar, but I'd rather keep it as uncluttered as possible for as long as possible.